# Как завершить сессию Windows 8.1 и зайти под другим пользователем в .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8

Имеется `Windows 8.1` необходимо чтобы программа завершила сеанс под тем пользователем, под которым она находится и зашла в систему под другим, чтобы далее выполнить какие то действия.

Права администратора у программы имеются если что.
Пользователи и пароли известны тоже естественно.

Как можно это реализовать под `.NET`?

Comment: Вы не сможете залогиниться под другим пользователем. Если вам нужно выполнить какие-то действия, вы можете запускать процессы от имени другого пользователя.

Comment: Нет нужно именно выйти и зайти под другим пользователем, запуск от имени другого пользователя даст совершенно другой результат.

Comment: Выход из системы завершит ваше приложение

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это утверждение применимо к любым типам программ? Или это частность к .NET? Может тогда мне стоит смотреть в сторону C++ ?

Comment: Хорошо, приложение не завершает один сеанс, но открывает другой сеанс и в нем выполняет действие, как с этим?

Comment: Это применимо ко всем "обычным" приложениям. Вам необходимо написать службу.

Comment: А я и не говорил что мне необходимо обычное приложение..., вопрос был можно ли это реализовать в .NET

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413961/4794368

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать это можно. Вам следует написать службу Windows, дать ей соответствующие права, убедиться что она добавилась в автозагрузку и тогда при запуске с достаточными правами доступа она сможет инициировать вход в сессию. На счет реализации, как правильно подсказали в комментариях, смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413900/launch-a-process-under-another-users-credentials/6413961#6413961). Но думаю с учетом специфики задачи, вам придется немного "потанцевать с бубном" загрузчика служб. Чтобы служба не прерывала свою работу.